# Two Sprite play the same action at the same time,the first one doesn't work

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CocosNode* spHead = [self getChildByTag:tagHead];
    CocosNode* spBody = [self getChildByTag:tagBody];

    [spHead runAction:fadeOutAction];
    [spBody runAction:fadeOutAction];
}
```

as the code above, i want the sprites to do some action at the same time, the second one works exactly, but the first one doesn't.

Need help.Anyone can help me?

Comment: it seems that using two action is OK.
like:
        [spHead runAction:fadeOutAction1];
        [spBody runAction:fadeOutAction2];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know

> - (BOOL) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
>     {
>         CocosNode* spHead = [self getChildByTag:tagHead];
>         CocosNode* spBody = [self getChildByTag:tagBody];

```
    [spHead runAction:fadeOutAction];
    [spBody runAction:[[fadeOutAction copy] autorelease]];
```

}

then ok

Answer (score 0):

Your fadeOutAction doesn't handle reentrancy?

Comment: I want them fade out and disppear.

Comment: I mean you can't call your fadeOutAction until the first one has completed.  It is not-stateless, and if you call it a second time while still running, it will reset the first one.  That may be why it doesn't work and having two different methods does.